# Respond to user control click

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have my user control with 25 panels and a function to wire all elements to same click.

[image]

```
    public shapeDisplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WireAllControls(this);
    }
    private void WireAllControls(Control cont)
    {            
        foreach (Control ctl in cont.Controls)
        {
            ctl.Click += ctl_Click;
            if (ctl.HasChildren)
            {
                WireAllControls(ctl);
            }
        }
    }
    private void ctl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.InvokeOnClick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

> Even when I use the recursive function to wire the controls, there isn't other containers on the controls, only the base control.

When control is selected i change the BackColor

```
this.backColor = Color.Black
```

When you click on one of the panel white area click works ok, but when you click in the control area (the black lines) click doesnt trigger.

Also you can see the cursor is a hand when is over a panel but then is an arrow when over a line.

I try adding

```
this.Click += ctl_Click;
cont.Click += ctl_Click;
```

But then all clicks stop working.

Comment: `this.Click` will add the event to the container which might be your form and that is why `this.Click += ctl_Click;` doesn't work for you.

Comment: Also, if the user clicks on the line which panel do you want to select (left or right, top or bottom)?

Comment: You should insert cont.Click += ctl_Click just before the for each instruction. But, as highligted by **rageit**, you must then differentiate the ctl_click code according to sender type (panel, form, ...) and eventually sender name.

Comment: @rageit this is a custom user control. `this` would be the control. When i add the control to my form I can click over the panels (inside control) but no over the lines. The click will change the BackColor for the user control

Comment: Remember that when you add event handler method to the container and then to elements inside container, that method will get fired on both containing and contained element. If fires on containing first so if the body of the method interrupts a thread, it will not fire on contained element.

Comment: @Graffito I try that and same effect like `this.Click += ctl_Click;` now control doesn't respong to click.

Comment: A dumb question, from where do you add events handler methods to this custom user control? Inside custom user control class object or from the containing Form class object?

Comment: @ark The code I show is the userControl side. This will trigger Click event on your form for this control when you click any area of the userControl. When you add the control to your form you will write the code when event occurs. In my case change BackColor to indicate selected control.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the border of the Panel itself is considered part of the "non-client" area, which triggers a WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN message.  You'll have to inherit from the Panel to trap that message (then place your new control into the UserControl instead of the stock Panel (it'll appear at the top of the toolbox once you recompile).

Here's a quick example:

```
public class myPanel : Panel
{

    private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN:
                this.InvokeOnClick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

}
```

*There are other ways you could trap the message as well, but I think this would be the easiest.

Comment: So I put my litle panels inside your panel sample? Doesnt your panel need `this.InvokeOnClick(this, EventArgs.Empty);` so when i put my UserControl on the form raise the event?

Comment: I updated the code.  No, you would **REPLACE** your panels with these new ones.  Once you've created the class and re-compiled the new control (called "myPanel" in my example) would appear at the top of your toolbox.  You'd delete your existing little panels and replace them with the new control.  The new control will raise the click event when it is clicked in the middle **and** when the border is clicked.

Comment: I think you missunderstand the issue. Right now my solution if i click on the minipanel work ok. The problem is on the area behind where I put the minipanels.

Comment: Ah...gotcha.  Can you show a zoomed in picture of the control and explain more about how those grid lines are made?